# ScrollView/TableView with UIControl/UIButton subviews not scrollable under iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios8, uicontrol

I've a UIScrollView instance (`scrollview`), and lots UIControl instances that lay on the scrollview as subviews. All works well before iOS 8, but the `scrollview` is not scrollable now under iOS 8.

Seems UIControl instances eat the touch event, and `scrollview`'s `delaysContentTouches` is broken under iOS 8.

---

Just found UITableView also has this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Searched for a while and got this issue fixed by

```
scrollview.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

---

And there's also another workaround (but I tried without lucky, cause UIControl instances not works then, let me know if u've any idea about it, thx):

```
if (floor((NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)) {
    UITapGestureRecognizer * nothingTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [nothingTap setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:nothingTap];
}
```